# In android app Open a browser in background

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.drexsprint.ardusecuv20;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void goToLeft(View view) {
        goToUrl("http://user:password@10.0.1.16/?button2");
    }

    public void goToRight(View view) {
        goToUrl("http://user:password@10.0.1.16/?button3");
    }

    public void goToTemp(View view) {
        goToUrl("http://user:password@10.0.1.16/?button1");
    }

    public void goToHum(View view) {
        goToUrl("http://user:password@10.0.1.16/button1");
    }

    public void goToPic(View view) {
        goToUrl("http://user:password@10.0.1.6/image.jpg"); // this works fine to take picture
    }

    private void goToUrl(String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }

}
```

-----------------------Layout--------------------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.drexsprint.ardusecuv20.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Humidty"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="goToHum"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        android:textColor="#101dae"
        android:backgroundTint="#d87c25" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rotate Left"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:onClick="goToLeft"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:textColor="#101dae"
        android:backgroundTint="#d87c25" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rotate Right"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.38"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="goToRight"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        android:textColor="#101dae"
        android:backgroundTint="#d87c25" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Temprt"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="goToTemp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#101dae"
        android:backgroundTint="#d87c25" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take a Photo"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="goToPic"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:textColor="#101dae"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:backgroundTint="#d87c25" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button5" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm trying to make an android app, by now i can click a button in the app and it does what i want it to do, the problem is it always take me to a browser , I would like it to execute the URL in background, or even don't load the browser but actually executes the command, any help!?

[image: The pic of my app]

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: let me add a picture and layout

Comment: what I'm trying t achieve is, right now when i click to lets say "Show Tempt" button it takes me to  {
        goToUrl("http://user:password@10.0.1.16/?button1"); I want it to do the same but this time executes the URL or the browser in background

Comment: You want to open the url in your application? Or you are  fetching JSON data from the url?

Comment: want the data from the url

Comment: but i would extremely appreciate a walk trough both ways, thanks!

Comment: I am still confused what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to click a button and while executing the url the apps  still there but the browser can open

Comment: in the background or in the app but what i dont want is the url make me leave the app

Comment: i hope i'm being clear

Comment: You dont want to open a browser, you want to call a webservice. Take a look at the URL class

Comment: can you walk me trough how to achieve that webservice call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open the urls in your application and you do not want to leave the app as it is starting the browser, for this you can use `WebView`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

public void btn1(View view) {
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://user:password@10.0.1.16/?button2");
}

public void btn2(View view) {
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://user:password@10.0.1.16/?button3");
}

public void btn3(View view) {
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://user:password@10.0.1.16/?button1");
}
```

}

Here is `main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn1" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="btn1"
    android:text="Link1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Link2"
    android:onClick="btn2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Link3"
    android:onClick="btn3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can try this.

Comment: I'm new to android and Java, can you kindly work me trough how should i introduce this modification  to my code, as i shared the code,Thanks!

Comment: I tried t use the code i get an error: Error:(28, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable myWebView

Comment: I did manage to get the code to work but when i launch the app and click the buttons the app just crash! Any Help!!!?

Comment: thanks the answer you gave me after some change on buttons name and add some web settings storage did work fine, but can you explain how to just fetch the URL! Appreciate

Comment: Anyone will help you here, just explain your problem very clearly.